# Set href based on page before last (-2) in history stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

What is the best say of setting the href based on the previous set of views in my ionic application? I understand that probably involves usage of [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) and [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/).

For instance if the page before last (-2) was `app.services` (as defined in app.js as below) - then the href will be set to `#/app/instant`:

```
  .state('app.services', {
    url: '/services/:business',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/services.html',
          controller: 'ServicesCtrl'      
        }
      }
  })
```

However if the page before last was `app.nearby` (as defined in app.js as below) - then the href will be set to `#/app/book`:

```
  .state('app.nearby', {
    url: '/nearby',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/nearby.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

Hence the code will probably looking something like this on the page that the URL that needs to be set (well at I least I think it will be):

```
<a class="button button-balanced"
style="border-radius:0px" ng-href='m ? "#/app/instant" : "#/app/book" '
href="">Book Now</a>
```

Where m is a call to the [$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/) function to figure out what view the user was on the page before last. However I am not really sure, if my reasoning is feasible.